# Facebook login fails with code 190 - "The access token was invalidated on the device"

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I've read all other related questions here, and found no answer.

I have been able to reproduce a scenario in which Facebook login fails with code 190, and a message of "The access token was invalidated on the device".

For some reason, it only happens when the user sets his credentials in the iOS Facebook settings page.  If the user is logged into Facebook in Safari (and only in Safari), then the authorize method works fine.

If the user is logged into Facebook in both Safari and iOS, authorize fails, and even numerous attempts fail (more than 10).

When I log out of iOS' Facebook settings page and keep Safari logged into Facebook, authorization succeeds.

I'm using the iPhone Simulator, so I don't have the Facebook App installed, and when my app calls `[facebook authorize]`, it opens up in Safari (if iOS settings are empty).

Facebook SDK 3.1.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well in the last few days. In the end my solution was to reset the iPhone simulator. You do so by:

1. Select iOS Simulator Menu
2. Select "Reset content and settings..."

Once I did this the authentication worked as normal.  In my case I believe the 190 error was being thrown due to having changed to a different FB account in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

This happened on my iPhone when I change my Facebook password.  Need to change your Facebook application password on the phone as well

Comment: Have you had this issue with an Iphone simulator as well?